# Keeping track of page number on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a web page which will be loaded with the contents of page one on load. Once the user scrolls the page I'm loading the contents of remaining pages using ajax call. What went wrong here is that I'm having a variable which will be initialized to 2 ( since page one is loaded on loading the page ) to keep track of the page number. What I thought is I would increment this variable once the user scrolls so that it would be pointing to the next page. But Its doesn't work. Its getting incremented before the ajax call is over. So Its missing out many pages. Can anyone tell me the better way to do this ? here is the code..

```
var pageNo = 2;

$(window).scroll(function() { if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() -$(window).height()) {

    console.log('pageNo ' + pageNo);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'url'+pageNo,
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        $.each(data,function(i, item) {
           var tp = $('content');
           $('#trpcontainer').append(tp);
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
}
  pageNo = pageNo + 1;
});
```

Comment: just put `pageNo = pageNo + 1;` inside the `success:` callback, ajax means asynchronous. javascript doesnt wait until ajax has finished

Comment: also, this is really bad practice. when the user uses the scroll wheel, a lot of scroll events are fired, meaning youre generating a lot of ajax triggers. use a pager instead and make a click function

Comment: Yes But the requirement is like that. I know its a bad practice that's why I asked for a better way to do the same. Anyway placing the increment statement inside success also didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This one in
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8zgu6nnv/)

Require Some Modification because also count UP Scrolling

**HTML**

```
  <div>Try scrolling the iframe.</div>
  <p>Paragraph - <span>Scroll happened!</span></p>
```

**JS**

```
  $( "p" ).clone().appendTo( document.body );
  $( "p" ).clone().appendTo( document.body );
  $( "p" ).clone().appendTo( document.body );
  $( "p" ).clone().appendTo( document.body );
  $( "p" ).clone().appendTo( document.body );
  var pag=0; 
  $( window ).scroll(function() {
  pag+=1;
  $( "span" ).css( "display", "inline").append(pag); 
  });
```