# jQuery scroll event: how to determine amount scrolled (scroll delta) in pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this event:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){    
    console.log(e);
})
```

I want to know, how much I have scroll value in pixels, because I think, scroll value depends from window size and screen resolution.

Function parameter `e` does not contains this information.
I can store `$(window).scrollTop()` after every scroll and calculate difference, but can I do it differently?

Comment: $(window).scrollTop();

Comment: Jonas Grumann, yes, but it all offset, i needs scroll value, how many pizels where scrolled on current event

Comment: [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928352/keeping-track-of-page-number-on-scroll-event/26929582#26929582)

Comment: not scroll count, scroll value in pixels

Comment: [Check this out.](http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-check-if-users-stop-scrolling/) You can modify it as per your needs.

Comment: What's your usage context? Why do you need to do this? You may get a more detailed answer with a little more info.

Comment: You generally don't want to know how much the user scrolled but how far the page has been scrolled in total, which is scrollTop / scrollLeft. Sometimes you want that in percentages, for instance when building responsive sites with parallax etc, but that's still the same thing you just divide scrollTop by the total height. The scroll event fires continously when scrolling, so you'll need to debounce it when getting the amount scrolled each time the user scrolls, and the result will not be very accurate and it's generally something you'd avoid doing.

Comment: Please show some HTML where you are using this. Пожалуйста, покажите немного HTML , где вы используете этот .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The "scroll value" does not depend on the window size or screen resolution. The "scroll value" is simply the number of pixels scrolled.

However, whether you are able to scroll at all, and the amount you *can* scroll is based on available real estate for the container and the dimensions of the content within the container (in this case the container is `document.documentElement`, or `document.body` for older browsers).

You are correct that the `scroll` event does not contain this information. It does not provide a `delta` property to indicate the number of pixels scrolled. This is true for the native `scroll` event and the jQuery `scroll` event. This seems like it would be a useful feature to have, similar to how `mousewheel` events provide properties for X and Y delta.

I do not know, and will not speculate upon, why the powers-that-be did not provide a `delta` property for `scroll`, but that is out of scope for this question (feel free to post a separate question about this).

The method you are using of storing `scrollTop` in a variable and comparing it to the current `scrollTop` is the best (and only) method I have found. However, you can simplify this a bit by extending jQuery to provide a new custom event, per this article: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/

Here is an example extension I created that works with window / document scrolling. It is a custom event called `scrolldelta` that automatically tracks the X and Y delta (as `scrollLeftDelta` and `scrollTopDelta`, respectively). I have not tried it with other elements; leaving this as exercise for the reader. This works in currrent versions of Chrome and Firefox. It uses the trick for getting the sum of `document.documentElement.scrollTop` and `document.body.scrollTop` to handle the bug where Chrome updates `body.scrollTop` instead of `documentElement.scrollTop` (IE and FF update `documentElement.scrollTop`; see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2891).

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tew9zxc1/

Runnable Snippet (scroll down and click `Run code snippet`):

```js
// custom 'scrolldelta' event extends 'scroll' event
jQuery.event.special.scrolldelta = {
    delegateType: "scroll",
    bindType: "scroll",
    handle: function (event) {
        var handleObj = event.handleObj;
        var targetData = jQuery.data(event.target);
        var ret = null;
        var elem = event.target;
        var isDoc = elem === document;
        var oldTop = targetData.top || 0;
        var oldLeft = targetData.left || 0;
        targetData.top = isDoc ? elem.documentElement.scrollTop + elem.body.scrollTop : elem.scrollTop;
        targetData.left = isDoc ? elem.documentElement.scrollLeft + elem.body.scrollLeft : elem.scrollLeft;
        event.scrollTopDelta = targetData.top - oldTop;
        event.scrollTop = targetData.top;
        event.scrollLeftDelta = targetData.left - oldLeft;
        event.scrollLeft = targetData.left;
        event.type = handleObj.origType;
        ret = handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments);
        event.type = handleObj.type;
        return ret;
    }
};

// bind to custom 'scrolldelta' event
$(window).on('scrolldelta', function (e) {
    var top = e.scrollTop;
    var topDelta = e.scrollTopDelta;
    var left = e.scrollLeft;
    var leftDelta = e.scrollLeftDelta;
  // do stuff with the above info; for now just display it to user
    var feedbackText = 'scrollTop: ' + top.toString() + 'px (' + (topDelta >= 0 ? '+' : '') + topDelta.toString() + 'px), scrollLeft: ' + left.toString() + 'px (' + (leftDelta >= 0 ? '+' : '') + leftDelta.toString() + 'px)';
    document.getElementById('feedback').innerHTML = feedbackText;
});
```

```css
#content {
    /* make window tall enough for vertical scroll */
    height: 2000px;
    /* make window wide enough for horizontal scroll */
    width: 2000px;
    /* visualization of scrollable content */
    background-color: blue;
}
#feedback {
    border:2px solid red;
    padding: 4px;
    color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', 'Arial';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='feedback'>scrollTop: 0px, scrollLeft: 0px</div>
<div id='content'></div>
```

Note that you may want debounce the event depending on what you are doing. You didn't provide very much context in your question, but if you give a better example of what you are actually using this info for we can provide a better answer. (Please show more of your code, and how you are using the "scroll value").

Comment: This code [is now hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/nothingisnecessary/jquery-scrolldelta)

Comment: The delta is not provided probably because the interval is unknown and thus sometimes a bit irrelevant. They would then have to provide the time from when this was recorded for you to be able to calculate some kind of scrolling speed, for example. Also this delta value would be strange to use when throttling ...

Answer (score 7):

To detemine how many pixels were scrolled you have to keep in mind that the `scroll` event gets fired almost every pixel that you move. The way to accomplish it is to save the previous scrolled value and compare that in a timeout. Like this:

```
var scrollValue = 0;
var scrollTimeout = false

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    /* Clear it so the function only triggers when scroll events have stopped firing*/
    clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    /* Set it so it fires after a second, but gets cleared after a new triggered event*/
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        var scrolled = $(document).scrollTop() - scrollValue;
        scrollValue = $(document).scrollTop();
        alert("The value scrolled was " + scrolled);
    }, 1000);
});
```

This way you will get the amount of scrolled a second after scrolling (this is adjustable but you have to keep in mind that the smooth scrolling that is so prevalent today has some run-out time and you dont want to trigger before a full stop).

Comment: You dont really need the timeout. How does that make any difference?

Comment: It lowers the amount of resources used and only calls your function when scrolling has ended. This is mostly because modern browsers keep scrolling a little bit more as it feels natural. Calling a jQuery function on a couple of hundred events every second is a bit... excessive.

Comment: Oh sorry (I just woke up when I replied to you), but the _main_ reason is that if you don't call it on a timeout, your scroll difference would always be 1 as you'd reset the `scrollValue` every time the event fires, meaning you would never know _how much was actually scrolled in total_, which was what the question was about :). (Thanks for the +1, I'm replying now just to be clear)

Comment: There are ways to scroll the content besides mouse & touch, like the keyboard (page up, page down, arrow keys up & down, home, end) that will result in `>1px` jumps of the scrollTop value. This may depend on the browser & OS (in my tests when using the `End` key in Firefox it fires multiple onscroll events, versus Chrome only firing one).

Comment: @nothingisnecessary I'm not sure what you want to say with this. Yes, there are other ways to scroll, but the function provided works universally because of the delay (no matter how much of them are fired, it will only look at the results after a second).

Comment: The timeout still gets cleared and created every time the event fires, you're not saving resources using this method.

Comment: Compared to what i would have to run I am saving resources. Whats so hard to understand here? Declaring a timeout and clearing is native, running jquery functions isn't. Arggg whatever.

Comment: Chill out dude, check your ego. Just because you are using a timeout doesn't inherently mean you are saving resources, your event still fires just as many times as it would if you didnt use a timeout. If we actually test the code w/timeout  http://jsfiddle.net/8senff7h/1/ to w/o timeout http://jsfiddle.net/8senff7h/ we can see that clearing and setting the timeout on average takes longer to process than just running the math itself. On my machine I am getting 0.015ms on running the math alone, as apposed to 0.029ms to clear and set a timeout.

Comment: Agree with CodeWizard. The debouncing doesn't seem appropriate at this level. When you care about scroll delta it is usually the case that you only care about the net change since the last time you cared about it. Also the one second delay (1000 ms I mean) seems like a lot of lag time from when the scrolling stops to when you do something with the delta.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary the amount of time is not set in stone, it was just an easy way to explain how I'd go about doing it. This is an easy way (much easier to comprehend) to get a scroll delta. About your answer - I haven;t tested it, but how do you even get a difference if you fire this on every scroll event? Just wondering. Happy to accept a better answer, but guys, you get hung up on the timeout - the timeout isn't actually there to save resources but mostly to be able to get a **delta**.

Comment: Question was lacking useful details, but OP stated they already knew how to get the delta using the exact method that you showed in your answer (minus the _debouncing_ which is what we call it when you use `setTimeout` to throttle back the event like you did). OP's question was "can i do it differently?" and mentioned the event didn't have amount scrolled. OP didn't say anything about needing to debounce, and because OP didn't specify the use case we don't know if it is necessary. For the record, I upvoted you first, but wanted to try my hand at a custom jQ event that provided the scroll data.

Answer (score 2):

The other way to do this? Yes, possible, with [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com)
I do not appreciate this solution, because it is necessary to include heavy jQuery mobile. Solution:

```
var diff, top = 0;
$(document).on("scrollstart",function () {
  // event fired when scrolling is started
  top = $(window).scrollTop();
});
$(document).on("scrollstop",function () {
  // event fired when scrolling is stopped
  diff = Math.abs($(window).scrollTop() - top);
});
```

Comment: I want, get value in pixels, when scroll event fired

Comment: add `px` string and you will get it in pixels, whats the problem?

Comment: `window` has not `scrollHeight` property

Comment: @zazu I dont see this to be more efficient that the most obvious solution that OP already stated in the question. You are making calls to 3 different functions in jQuery as opposed to 2 (which are the same functions) in the obvious one.

Comment: @RahulDesai if scroll direction is different (scrolled to top for example), will it work?

Comment: so, i am scroll and get 0, -100, -200, -300 etc, but i want get value of scroll only

Comment: @AndreyVorobyev You should get the value of scroll height left after the place have scrolled. If you need positive number you have to make it absolute.

Comment: it's scroll offset, i am needs scroll value

Comment: Please write what you want in Russian, otherwise I cant understand :)

Comment: You understand russian? =)

Comment: @AndreyVorobyev yes :)

Comment: Вообщем. Я хочу определять величину скролла. То есть, произошло событие прокрутки, и надо знать, на сколько пикселей была прокручена страница

Comment: Обновил свой ответ, но не советую его использовать :) т.к. мобильный jQuery весит целых 200кб.  Думаю просто надо взять на заметку и забыть о нем :)

Comment: Спасибо, круто. Как по мне лучше смотрится чем с таймаутами.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the used processing power by adding a timer to a Jquery scroll method is probably not a great idea. The visual effect is indeed quite bad.

The whole web browsing experience could be made much better by hiding the scrolling element just when the scroll begins and making it slide in (at the right position) some time after. The scrolling even can be checked with a delay too.
This solution works great.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var element = $('.movable_div'),
    originalY = element.offset().top;
    element.css('position', 'relative');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        element.hide();
        element.stop(false, false).animate({
            top: scrollTop < originalY
                    ? 0
                    : scrollTop - originalY + 35
        }, 2000,function(){element.slideDown(500,"swing");});
    });
});
```

Live demo [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPLzqQ)