# Xpath select first level childs

Tags: xpath

I have document

```
<ul class="section">
 <li>
 <ul class="section">
  <li><span>world</span></li>
 </ul>
 <span>hello</span>
 </li>
 <li><span>!</span></li>
</ul>
```

I want to select `li` on first level, and i have xpath expression:

```
//ul[@class="section"]/li
```

But it selects all `li`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do that can be: `ul[@class="section" and not(parent::li)]/li`

Comment: @AndreyVorobyev Please do not forget to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem. Thanks! And you should to the same for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26992079/1987598) or otherwise react to it.